# Cannot add or update child row. A foreign key constraint failed

Tags: mysql, database

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to edit a previously set `NOT NULL` field to accept `NULL` values.

And I'm getting this error when I try to insert a record:

`A foreign key constraint failed.`

---

There are two tables in my schema , one called `Customer` and another called `referralAgent`, having an ***one-to-many*** relationship defined between them, using the `referralAgentId` as a foreign key for the customer table.

Although there are not any `NOT NULL` constraints in the fields of the parent table i.e `customer` , i can't insert a `NULL` value in the foreign key field.

[image: A screenshot of my schema]

---

And the `CREATE TABLE` code:

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `watson_schema`.`referralagent` (
  `idReferralAgent` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `test` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idReferralAgent`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `watson_schema`.`customer` (
  `idUser` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `postCode` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `profession` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `phoneNumWork` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `phoneNumMobile` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `phoneNumHome` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `countryResidence` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `countryBirth` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `entityStatusIdStatus` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `ReferralAgent_idReferralAgent` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser`),
  INDEX `fk_Customers_nationality1_idx` (`nationality` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Customers_Country1_idx` (`countryResidence` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Customers_Country2_idx` (`countryBirth` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Customer_EntityStatus1_idx` (`entityStatusIdStatus` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Customer_ReferralAgent1_idx` (`ReferralAgent_idReferralAgent` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Customers_Country1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`countryResidence`)
    REFERENCES `watson_schema`.`country` (`idCountry`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Customers_Country2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`countryBirth`)
    REFERENCES `watson_schema`.`country` (`idCountry`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Customers_nationality1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nationality`)
    REFERENCES `watson_schema`.`nationality` (`idNationality`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Customer_EntityStatus1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`entityStatusIdStatus`)
    REFERENCES `watson_schema`.`entitystatus` (`idStatus`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Customer_ReferralAgent1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ReferralAgent_idReferralAgent`)
    REFERENCES `watson_schema`.`referralagent` (`idReferralAgent`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 21
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

INSERT INTO `watson_schema`.`customer`
(`idUser`,
`firstName`,
`lastName`,
`address`,
`postCode`,
`profession`,
`phoneNumWork`,
`phoneNumMobile`,
`phoneNumHome`,
`nationality`,
`countryResidence`,
`countryBirth`,
`entityStatusIdStatus`,
`ReferralAgent_idReferralAgent`)
VALUES
("22",
"Giannis",
"Komikos",
"Theofilou",
"2242",
"Coffeeman",
"22345672",
"99874568",
"22454547",
"6",
"2",
"3",
"5",
"");
```

Comment: Please post your related table structures' code (`create table code`)

Comment: code posted :P @SubrataDeyPappu

Comment: please show the full insert statement (with values of course) which caused the error.

Comment: Insert code posted @SubrataDeyPappu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not inserting null. You are inserting an empty string. Either leave ReferralAgent_idReferralAgent out of the insert statement OR change the last value in the insert statement from "" to NULL. The insert fails because there is no key in the parent table that equates to "".

Comment: thx a lot . it works if i leave the ReferralAgent_idReferralAgent out of the insert statement. Changing the value from "" to NULL doesn't work @ojf

Comment: It should work. Don't quote it. So NULL not "NULL". Glad its fixed though